# How to create a unit test with a mocked class that uses Testcaf&#233;&#39;s TestController?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a test that mocks a class using typemoq but i have an issue with one of its function.
In this function I call Testcafé's TestController to use a specific Role but it does not work as expected.

What can I do in order to have an instance of TestController that I can use outside a testcafé test?

Here is an example test:

```js
import {IMock} from "typemoq/Api/IMock";
import {Mock} from "typemoq";
import {Role, t} from "testcafe";
import { expect } from "chai";

class TestClass {
  public static async useRole(role: Role): Promise<boolean> {
    await t.useRole(role);
    return true;
  }
}

describe("test mock using Testcafé's TestController", () => {
  it('should switch role', async () => {
    const role = Role.anonymous();
    const mockedClass: IMock<typeof TestClass> = Mock.ofType<typeof TestClass>();

    mockedClass.setup(x => x.useRole(role)).returns(async (role) => {
      return TestClass.useRole(role);
    });

    const result = await mockedClass.object.useRole(role);

    expect(result).to.eq(true);
  });
});
```

When debugging you should get this:

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use TestCafe functions only if a browser is opened and a TestCafe test is running, so they will not work in custom code.

The `useRole` method (and most of other methods) also works only when a browser is opened because the browser and server code interact inside this method. `useRole` is designed to get cookies and local storage from the client side. So, even if you were able to mock the `useRole` method, it would lose the most important part of its logic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I agree mocking ```useRole``` is not the solution and sadly it seems to have no alternative at the moment